# How to set and get parameters in calling function?

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function with three parameters from another function and call the second function on button click:

```
function test(p1, p2, p3) {
        if (document.getElementById("p1").value == "") {
            document.getElementById("p2").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = "no not today";
 }
```

This function test() will be called on click:

```
function param() {
        test("text1", "welcome1", "g1");
        test("text2", "welcome2", "g2");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Attention with your error : 
**p1, p2, p3 are the arguments of the function test() and they are variables here**

```
function test(p1, p2, p3) {
    if (document.getElementById("p1").value == "") { // It's false because "p1" is string, it isn't the varibale p1
      ...
    }
```

You must write the code as following

```
 function test(p1, p2, p3) {
     if (document.getElementById(p1).value == "") { // It's true because it's called with the variable p1
       ...
     }
```

**Bonus** : for ensuring the reliability of the code, you must check the elements with id p1, p2 are existed in DOM ?

```
function test(p1, p2, p3) {
    if (document.getElementById(p1) && document.getElementById(p1).value == "") {
       ...
    }
```

Comment: To clearify it further: in `document.getElementById()` the arguments `p1`, `p2` and `p3` were set in quotes, making them Strings instead of using the value of the variables.

Comment: as @Tsunamis said, you must ensure the value of the variables p1, p2 is a string and you should verify  if (document.getElementById(p1)) existed