# Unable to understand why the following JavaScript function is not working

Tags: javascript, function

I am new to Java Script and I am unable to understand why the following function is not working, what am I doing wrong here? Its prompting me to enter the var gender value but once I enter it is not executing any further. Given below the JavaScript code I am trying to run.

```js
var gender = prompt('What is your gender..?');

function name(fname = 'Sayantan', mname, lname = 'Choudhury') {
  if (gender == male) {
    document.write('Hello Mr. ' + fname + ' ' + mname + ' ' + lname + '<br/>');
  } else {
    document.write('Hello Mrs. ' + fname + ' ' + mname + ' ' + lname + '<br/>');
  }
}

name('Mridula', 'Dutta', 'Chowdhury');
name('Mridula');
```

Comment: male is not variable it should be in quotes like if (gender == 'male')

Comment: gender == 'male'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

male is not variable here so you want to compare it with string like `'male'`
You also should check by converting gender to lower case so it can support case insensitive.

also there is one more problem if you don't pass mname you will see undefined in-between first and last name.

```js
var gender = prompt('Gender');
function name(fname = 'Sayantan', mname = '', lname = 'Choudhury') {
  let title = 'Mrs'
  if (gender.toLowerCase() === 'male') {
    title = 'Mr';
  }
  document.write('Hello'+ title + '. ' + fname + ' ' + mname + (mname ? ' ' : '') + lname + '<br/>')
}

name('Mridula', 'Dutta', 'Chowdhury');
name('Mridula');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use male as male instead of 'male' javascript thinks that male is a variable declared somewhere in your code and throws an error because it doesn't exist(at least in your case), but what you enter inside prompt is stored in gender variable and it contains the string 'male' which you entered so the condition should be:

```
if(gender === 'male')
```

or

```
if(gender === 'female')
```

`===` compares the type along with value, if you only want to compare the value then you can use `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Attention in your code `gender == male` : **whether male is a variable or male is a string 'male' ?**

I suggest that you want to write the string 'male' because I don't see the declaration of `the variable male`. So in this case, you must write the code : `gender === "male"`

Moreover, I don't neither see the declaration of `the variable gender` in your code. I recommend you be attention for declaration of identifier names (variables and functions) in the code. Example : so you could respect the [camelCase](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp). It's a good pratice !

An example :

```
function fncCheckName (name, mName, lName) { }
```

---

You could view also my answer in the another post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60037641/4386148